# CSS menu with width 100%

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with ul/li but I want it to take all the available width and distribute the size between the li's inside it.

Is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: show your code, and you will avoid negative votes

Comment: You mean like the Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, and Unanswered buttons up top?

Comment: I tried! but that was too fast :)

Comment: there is no code, that's what I was trying to get. Thanks for the help

Comment: Oops.. Uhh.. Just realized I was the down voter.. I could've sworn it was an upvote.. It won't let me change it.. :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *table* styles. Note that these are not supported in < IE8.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
   display: table; 
   width: 100%;
}

ul li {
   display: table-cell; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/v937B/).

The borders in the jsFiddle there are for visual aid only. They are not necessary.

Comment: @alex I'm just curious because of your selector **ul li**. Is this a practice I should consider? (I figure li is always a child of ul anyways).

Comment: @Marty It could be the child of `ol` :P But in this example, I could have omitted it.

Comment: hmmmmmmm why not use table instead then?

Comment: @Bruno The `table` element implies that the containing information is tabular data. A menu is **not** tabular data.

Comment: @Bruno Yep, that is an issue.